# css multi columns, appending columns on the left side

Tags: css

Is it possible to fill columns dynamically in css in a way, that each additional column is added on the *left* side of a full one?
e.g.

```
----------
|  4 | 1 |
|    | 2 |
|    | 3 |
----------
```

I already discovered the webkit-clumns properties, but these align from left to right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe using flex but having the flex parent with the rule text-align:right; will do as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `direction: rtl;` applied to the columns container (and use the opposite value for the inner elements), e.g.

**Codepen** : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdxKbw

---

Markup

```
<main>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</main>
```

CSS

```
main {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
  height    : 600px;
  direction : rtl; 
}

p {
  direction : ltr; 
   -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
             page-break-inside: avoid;
                  break-inside: avoid;
   height   : 150px;
   margin   : 0 0 2em 0;
   padding  : 0;
   border   : 1px #ccc dashed;
}
```

---

**Result** (tested on Chrome)

[image]

Comment: great solution! Works also with ul and li elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with `display: flex;` by using the [`flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp) property.
Just make sure to check [browser compatability](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Also see [this useful guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information.

For example:

```css
.flex-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.flex-item {
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
    <div class="flex-item"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><p>4</p></div>
</div>
```